# c# converting string Encode Non Ascii Characters

Tags: c#, encode

I have this UI that needs unicode values to display superscript Characters. the data is coming inbound has html code.The only problem I can see is that it needs an extra backslash. I am passing a string of "®" into EncodeNonAsciiCharacters.

> Is there any way to return `\u00AE` and not `\\u00AE`

```
static string EncodeNonAsciiCharacters(string value)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (char c in value)
    {
        if (c > 127)
        {
            string encodedtext = ((int)c).ToString("x4");
            //string encodedValue = "\\u" + encodedtext.ToUpper();
            string encodedValue = @"\u" + encodedtext.ToUpper();
                sb.Append(encodedValue);
        }
        else
        {
            sb.Append(c);
        }
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Aren't C# `string`s UTF-16 already?

Comment: This is fundamentally wrong because C# chars are 16-bit UTF-16LEs, not 8-bit UTF8s.

Comment: You're not "returning" `\\u00AE`. You need to write `\\u` in your code editor because `\ ` is an escape character in C# string literals. You could write `@"\u"` instead if you wanted.

Comment: When you see "\\u1234" in the debugger, it actually represents the string @"\u1234".  It *escapes* the backslash by doubling it up

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have written a program to demonstrate your requirement. You do not need to escape string literals if you use @ before your string. It means to interpret the string literally (that is, you cannot escape any characters within the string if you use the @ prefix). It enhances readability in cases where it can be used.

```
using System;
using System.Text;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
            string value="⁸ ⁹ ⁺ ⁻ ⁼ ⁽ ⁾ ₀ ₁ ₂ ₃ ₄ ₅ ₆ ₇ ₈ ₉ ₊ ₋ ₌ ₍ ₎ ®";
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (char c in value)
            {
                if (c > 127)
                {
                    string encodedtext = ((int)c).ToString("x4");
                    string encodedValue = @"\u" + encodedtext.ToUpper();
                    sb.Append(encodedValue);
                    //Console.WriteLine(encodedValue);
                }
                else
                {
                    sb.Append(c);
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
    }
}
```

Output:

```
\u2078 
\u2079 
\u207A 
\u207B 
\u207C 
\u207D 
\u207E 
\u2080 
\u2081 
\u2082 
\u2083 
\u2084 
\u2085 
\u2086 
\u2087 
\u2088 
\u2089 
\u208A 
\u208B 
\u208C 
\u208D 
\u208E 
\u00AE
```

Comment: should the WriteLine display the symbol ? And not the encode value?

Comment: It won't display the symbol since you are converting the symbol to its hex value and then prefixing the \u to  the encoded value.